# How to send cookie (header) using Python requests library

Tags: python, cookies, python-requests, session-cookies

Hi I am new with python requests and would like to have some help.

When I try to use python requests and get the session cookie, use the following command:

```
session_req = requests.session()    

result = session_req.get(
 get_url
)
```

after execute GET from requests, I use the '.cookies' property ant the respective key I want to send at the POST Header, I get the value successfully, but the POST action is not working.

```
session_req.cookies['IFCSHOPSESSID']
```

but when I get the request from the same API via POSTMAN and try to get the cookie property (exporting the code as python requests) I found some differences, and if I use this same cookie exported from POSTMAN it works.

**POSTMAN EXAMPLE**

```
'cookie': 'IFCSHOPSESSID=hrthhiqdeg0dvf4ecooc83lui3; nikega=GA1.4.831513767.1599354095; nikega_gid=GA1.4.1839484382.1599354095; _ga=GA1.3.831513767.1599354095; _gid=GA1.3.733956911.1599354099; chaordic_browserId=0-fv_3j6NdVlbNFFwPRzUGQVse7e1bbqga-3OS1599354098234702; chaordic_anonymousUserId=anon-0-fv_3j6NdVlbNFFwPRzUGQVse7e1bbqga-3OS1599354098234702; chaordic_testGroup=%7B%22experiment%22%3Anull%2C%22group%22%3Anull%2C%22testCode%22%3Anull%2C%22code%22%3Anull%2C%22session%22%3Anull%7D; user_unic_ac_id=bec863cf-4e06-0ab1-d881-b566595d3e8f; _gcl_au=1.1.1305519862.1599354100; _fbp=fb.2.1599354100232.504934336; smeventsclear_16df2784b41e46129645c2417f131191=true; smViewOnSite=true; __pr.cvh=4ftsyf8x16; _gaexp=GAX1.3.tupm6REJTMeD-piAakRDMA.18557.0; blueID=75a502b6-e7c2-4eb3-8442-75aea5d95fdc; _cm_ads_activation_retry=false; sback_client=5816989a58791059954e4c52; sback_partner=false; sb_days=1599356617672; sback_refresh_wp=no; smClickOnSite=true; smClickOnSite_652c0aaee02549a3a6ea89988778d3fc=true; _rtbhouse_source_=socialminer; RKT=false; dedup=socialminer; lmd_cj=socialminer; advcake_url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.nike.com.br%2Flancamentos%3Futm_source%3Dsocialminer%26utm_medium%3Dsocialminer_onsitedesktop%26utm_campaign%3Dsocialminer_onsitedesktop_lancamentos_desk%26smid%3D3-17; advcake_trackid=dd7e2ef0-dd50-889a-aeea-559a0d8bcd22; advcake_utm_content=socialminer_onsitedesktop_lancamentos_desk; advcake_utm_campaign=socialminer; Campanha=; Parceiro=; Midia=; AMCVS_F0935E09512D2C270A490D4D%40AdobeOrg=1; s_cc=true; lmd_orig=direct; SIZEBAY_SESSION_ID=0AC1A70CB19F4f03610665d04bb088ef3b9af0942fc8; sback_customer_w=true; sback_browser=0-87718800-1599408894bff13e290b9fee5fc2b430382f639b87dd9cf25112334287575f550afed62983-14051381-17920887216,13017640152-1599408894; sback_access_token=eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJpc3MiOiJhcGkuc2JhY2sudGVjaCIsImlhdCI6MTU5OTQwODg5NSwiZXhwIjoxNTk5NDk1Mjk1LCJhcGkiOiJ2MiIsImRhdGEiOnsiY2xpZW50X2lkIjoiNTgxNjk4OWE1ODc5MTA1OTk1NGU0YzUyIiwiY2xpZW50X2RvbWFpbiI6Im5pa2UuY29tLmJyIiwiY3VzdG9tZXJfaWQiOiI1ZjU0M2VjODA5ZjFkMDkzMmQzMjQ2OTUiLCJjdXN0b21lcl9hbm9ueW1vdXMiOmZhbHNlLCJjb25uZWN0aW9uX2lkIjoiNWY1NDNlYzgwOWYxZDA5MzJkMzI0Njk2IiwiYWNjZXNzX2xldmVsIjoiY3VzdG9tZXIifX0.K6FYVBasHjMg_PLbT1yZfrnIp97USqijoMObF4eUSms.WrWrDrHeHezRqBiYiYHeDr; sback_customer=$2gSxATWYdVYOVGMI10bUdkW2pWeoZERU1kc1YWWhd1SNR0aMJ0QUVzTHpHdJZERnpVS6FTSkRUTOBjMys2bUdnT2$12; sback_pageview=false; ak_bmsc=B6177778CB59637165F7EC43342C1559C9063147DA220000234E555F8D78F831~plACNrc4cNxoHZNcO7aF4o+U0KQNKjzPECGSfb42NdayPvdNkBWwUT9QOhGjuLJJ3vStuFIRkiI/35wsHEyUE3/h2guphhaEy71BnfekvDtb/6F84hS+fWhPxxVG5RAlph8WzGpYMn6NZESNVcgnZYfH4HoZ/IzBPR6AMG9UGn6W4xm/j/j9kOfef8v/fZf2pXw4mxJuiN5Cxc7g2sV4nCdoEW98Q4AgqplzxWZjpamZk=; bm_sz=6586256DDAFC895D740341E4214D0D40~YAAQRzEGybYT7yN0AQAAfDw5ZQnXjJtKI2SxkwQFV9vLZpF5mACXNUtUFDSkidKuYM2fac5sQgRozU9fA3+017dht/PUtH+wtibATtTmoVOlpKnW+V76+1rySk3HK6q83Q9rtQc/LaaQ8VYtK/tDi0VOc7/0wLyKy/+Z4OLtgUpySYZZcEX4k8/46no8rFD6OQ==; AMCV_F0935E09512D2C270A490D4D%40AdobeOrg=359503849%7CMCIDTS%7C18512%7CMCMID%7C56897587165425478193529762442649463163%7CMCAAMLH-1600030892%7C4%7CMCAAMB-1600030892%7CRKhpRz8krg2tLO6pguXWp5olkAcUniQYPHaMWWgdJ3xzPWQmdj0y%7CMCOPTOUT-1599433292s%7CNONE%7CMCSYNCSOP%7C411-18519%7CvVersion%7C5.0.1; sback_total_sessions=3; sback_session=5f554e3c73a63da56d739d87; lmd_traf=direct-1599402359608&direct-1599408890286&direct-1599414284313&direct-1599427194077; chaordic_realUserId=2962653; chaordic_session=1599429266491-0.4343169041143473; _st_ses=49222273669791505; _st_cart_script=helper_nike.js; _st_cart_url=/; _sptid=1592; _spcid=1592; _st_id=cnVkc29ucmFtb25AZ21haWwuY29t; _st_idb=cnVkc29ucmFtb25AZ21haWwuY29t; lx_sales_channel=%5B%222%22%5D; sback_cart=5f555ba24f507d767721c387; CSRFtoken=1ac8a198f88ac1ccc1f8555ab41c8a95; gpv_v70=nikecombr%3Echeckout%3Eaddress; pv_templateName=CHECKOUT; gptype_v60=checkout%3Aaddress; stc119288=env:1599429270%7C20201007215430%7C20200906222939%7C5%7C1088071:20210906215939|uid:1599354102799.1149977977.6705985.119288.1871143352:20210906215939|srchist:1088071%3A1599429270%3A20201007215430:20210906215939|tsa:1599429270805.1898407973.364911.7635034620790062.2:20200906222939; bm_sv=C9C3A8C6B2F6CB232317BB794ADC0497~ZnoksXquh4Yrh4uN87gycXdh+ixzU+xMFsb94sO9uE5JMLyZz9eJPp5odX7vx944KIXG1nvOxuq8pdrQUDjBrchRJLC4yiD1yWX0h4BjWhZwbfHPtnzaT3ASbIZnf2Ts1TRt+ZAescJJwrNPs4oV2If7vyiWi2AYILFvCstCTS8=; _uetsid=a9a0bfd4fe4e4db52bcd4ca66850a785; _uetvid=9ba47ed116a48f496f6b1a9844e21c95; __udf_j=f08aeb668454efbf6ddc83dd9d4b7a8385abde9f9fbd92526f1de0441da2126ec40330dfc36d0b9c3eae98557c94447d; _spl_pv=40; s_sq=lojanike-new-production%252Clojanike-nikebr%3D%2526c.%2526a.%2526activitymap.%2526page%253Dnikecombr%25253Echeckout%25253Eaddress%2526link%253DSeguir%252520para%252520pagamento%2526region%253Didentificacao-form%2526pageIDType%253D1%2526.activitymap%2526.a%2526.c%2526pid%253Dnikecombr%25253Echeckout%25253Eaddress%2526pidt%253D1%2526oid%253DSeguir%252520para%252520pagamento%2526oidt%253D3%2526ot%253DSUBMIT; RT="z=1&dm=nike.com.br&si=92b42534-25ee-4155-aa1a-e7d127581869&ss=kermvxyl&sl=9&tt=17e8&bcn=%2F%2F173e2544.akstat.io%2F"; _abck=F6E1C280C3F9D735A2B1AB62443DB479~-1~YAAQVjEGycno+iJ0AQAAmtRxZQT8kxLFalTup4dkYT5+cq/PavPcY4/0zAeJv4GoSQQwYVj4EWydkfxbJR3Rgaa4k6ma+5O72J/lsiajATrx0oaZJuB5b/FIP6RymanPRVGlb3kLJXpBQDkCmVv62kkxLKxySrlAYDCg0ORCpSXlTCbFBVEchC9ih5t094egSeVdM6VjfQSO9uDKISBoP4923qkJMTpbk9B1nOoiylKK+y+FGFu8pzEpQqZYj7tIMTJVpqe0OpXaQ8m8nPyp0K+PmBcAndIHcBMTZUEqma9/72Enx8yvGbKXrYbAzNDw6ZtKY9OAbNuVeqprza/Af0aUkinm0l3JqxjTH1LpglNxNN4=~-1~-1~-1; CSRFtoken=20a208bad599aa3ead0bbe944b27a368; bm_sv=C9C3A8C6B2F6CB232317BB794ADC0497~ZnoksXquh4Yrh4uN87gycXdh+ixzU+xMFsb94sO9uE5JMLyZz9eJPp5odX7vx944KIXG1nvOxuq8pdrQUDjBrchRJLC4yiD1yWX0h4BjWhbSXhHWWrgkUsOTt9033P5Wxu1qmo5M6w0VAWeAzBaCN7yZC2Ll7DiGq0CwpjxlOW4=; _abck=F6E1C280C3F9D735A2B1AB62443DB479~-1~YAAQVjEGyRKO+iJ0AQAA+4U9ZQSNIWTEz/60Uk5gz2tnzVtbMbX0hpaMbkbeJxSYSMD1xo7TTedXnJ0UuTLxxcHhLVrRRCrZfSjZ+yH00Ld6FLIajmYFefKPehzA6GgwjnLyucI1O6nDw2ZU1CV0WJLeWGgcmX7sinsLr3DVtmoGJyNR1Q9EWpvq71/W1Ys4Bqhq1628YKEz/0Z1Ic1bWMujcG03064ZZYYXTSTz9jrkxHKaEoJQNQgyUg9NXQhv4EFoMSESy/AIKRy+hVCULLJscbkpH8WakuvYQ1raghVfheks/Xra9AmiUoOqAbWAPXOij1nWQ9PSV2hxQZfkibD0+YP14pTXPoCAUA9jCQHRJIw=~0~-1~-1'
```

**session_req.cookies['IFCSHOPSESSID'] EXAMPLE**

```
qnabtagl4pu7gm2jg3sij03cu6
```

Other curious thing is that when I use the '.cookies' property, my POST call return sucess even without update the cart where it should be inserting a new register.

As I am trying to develop one site bot, I would like to generate this same cookie via python requests code. Can anyone try to help me on it?

Comment: No need to send cookies explicitly, session object will handle that. Before doing the post request, do a get request to the cookies to be set.

Comment: but, how could I execute it? Because, when I try to execute without explicitly inform the cookie, I send the post to the respective URL, it return me 200, but it not updating the Cart Item I sent at the POST request.

post = session_req.post(
login_url,
data = payload
)

<Response [200]>

Comment: Can you share you code or URL you are trying, so i can try it on my system?

Comment: On first, I use the url
 - login_url = "https://www.nike.com.br/Produto/Meia-Nike-Everyday-Cushion-Crew-3-pares/67-68-73-14919#"
 - get_url = "https://www.nike.com.br/Produto/Meia-Nike-Everyday-Cushion-Crew-3-pares/67-68-73-14919?site_id=106"

Comment: second, I get the session
 - session_req = requests.session()


# getting the CSRF token

login = session_req.get(login_url)

login_html = html.fromstring(login.content)
authenticity_token = list(set(login_html.xpath("//input[@type='hidden']/@value")))[0]

print(authenticity_token)

Comment: ## the login is working, but the POST requests is not

# using the field name used to inform the email and password

payload = {
    "emailAddress":"someEmail@test.com",
    "password":"thePassword",
    "CSRFtoken": authenticity_token
}

###  POST REQUEST

# POST request

post = session_req.post(
login_url,
data = payload
)
## it returns 200, but the add cart acction do not reflect the item sent

Comment: Looks like a contender for `selenium`. Some `javascript` is being executed when Add to Cart is clicked, thus `request` will not be do this as it doesn't execute javascript.

Comment: There is a way to get this javascript and execute it via selenium? I know I can use the execute scripts from selenium to simulate the same behavior.

Comment: Yes Rudson, you can automate the click behaviour using selenium and `driver.execute_script`

Answer (score 0):

This is an example with **python 3**. You can customize it.

```
import requests

data ="param_1=value_1&param_2=value_2&.....&param_n=value_n"; #your request parameters.
cookie = "cookie_name=xxxxxxxx;....." #define cookie
url_endpoint = "htpps://........." # your url endpoint
# add cookies to endpoints
resp = requests.get(url_endpoint, data=data.encode('utf-8'),cookies=cookie)
if(resp.status_code==200):
    print("success ")
else:
    print("error ")
```

Comment: Thanks in advance for your example, but I know how to send the cookie using requests libray, what I am looking for is how to achieve it dinamically.
The scenario is that I could make a login and get the session, but when I use the requests, with the same session, it is not working to post the data.